# How to stub parent and child class in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I have a class structure in a Rails (v7) app that looks like this:

```rb
# app/services/email_notifier.rb
class EmailNotifier
  def notify(template_data)
    # do things with email client
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/services/email_notifier/template_data.rb
class EmailNotifier
  class TemplateData
    def fill_in
      # do things with template and email client
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/services/notification_service.rb
class NotificationService
  def call
    template_content = EmailNotifier::TemplateData.new(name: 'John Doe')
    EmailNotifier.notify(template_content)
  end
end
```

And what I'm trying to do is verify that the class methods are called:

```rb
# spec/services/notification_service.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe NotificationService do
  subject(:service) { described_class.new }
  let(:email_notifier) { class_double(EmailNotifier).as_stubbed_const }
  let(:email_template_class) { class_double(EmailNotifier::TemplateData).as_stubbed_const }
  let(:email_template) { instance_double(EmailNotifier::TemplateData) }

  before do
    allow(email_notifier).to receive(:notify)
    allow(email_template_class).to receive(:new).and_return(:email_template)
    allow(email_template).to receive(:fill_in)
  end

  it 'fills the template in' do
    service.call

    expect(email_template).to have_received(:fill_in)
  end
end
```

When I run rspec, I get this error:

```
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant #<ClassDouble(EmailNotifier) (anonymous)>::TemplateData

                 template_content = EmailNotifier::TemplateData.new
```

Now, I understand that I could be facing a problem from different origins:

1. the structure I use is not being correctly interpreted by class loader when running the spec
2. the "parent" class is stubbed and it cannot get its "child" class

As I suspect that what is happening is **2.**, the question is how can I make this kind of stub happen? Is this possible? Am I facing it in a wrong way?

I'm not sure `stub_const` works either as I expect in this spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why mock the classes when you're stubbing the methods?

```
    allow(EmailNotifier).to receive(:notify)
    allow(EmailNotifier::TemplateData).to receive(:fill_in)
```

Comment: I'll update the answer to include some more logic; I'm going to use the instances, and I understand using the mocks that way is the recommended way to provide mocks (that's why, but I could be wrong).

Comment: Updated; the part of your answer that works is that I should not mock the `EmailNotifier`.

Comment: Additionally: your answer worked, but the question remains: is it possible to nest "stubbing constants", as they being nested classes?

Comment: Because of lots and lots of lazy loading and depending on how you define these classes, it is possible your let statement never executes.  Maybe if you use let! instead...